# This loop counts the number of occurrences of a substring inside a string, How?

Tags: java, loops

```
public static int keywordCount (String str, String substr) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((str.indexOf(substr, i)) != -1) {
          count++;
          i += substr.length();
    }
    System.out.println(count);

    return count;
}
```

This is a sample loop example from my teacher. I really need some explanation to understand, how this loop works ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What don't you understand, _specifically_?

Comment: the ((str.indexOf(substr, i)) != -1) part of the loop, I don't quite how it processes. I only know it is a condition for the loop to start and end.

Comment: study indexOf() function and you will find out. it is simple actually

Comment: [Here's the `String` class javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: @Johnny see documentation.

Comment: indexOf(String substring,int start); Searches in this string for the index of the specified string. The search for the string starts at the specified offset and moves towards the end of this string.Inside the loop start is being updated so next time it searches from updated value of the start. ((str.indexOf(substr, i)) != -1) is being used to reach the end of the string. if str.indexof() = end of the file loop will not proceed anymore.

Comment: Actually, this code is buggy.  `keyWordCount("alfalfa", "alfa")` returns `1`, but it should be `2`.

Comment: Note that if you look for ss in sssss, this method will find 2 and not 4 occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) method, which is defined in the Javadoc as,

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index. ... If no such value of k exists, then -1 is returned.

Note that `i` is the index (so `i += substr.length();` means it will move forward the length of the match). When there are no more matches the method returns -1 and that ends your loop. Also, I think this

```
while ((str.indexOf(substr, i)) != -1)
```

Was supposed to be

```
while ((i = str.indexOf(substr, i)) != -1)
```

Then I believe the logic is correct. Or,

```
i = substr.length() + str.indexOf(substr, i);
```

Comment: Logically it should 'i += str.indexOf(substr, i) + 1'. You need to jump to first occurrence (from index) plus one char, not to length of sub-string

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop, so there's no need to understand one.

You also need only a tiny amount of code with a good approach:

```
public static int keywordCount(String str, String substr) {
    return str.replace(substr, substr + "x").length() - str.length();
}
```

Simplicity is at the heart of elegance.

Answer (score 0):

Here str.indexOf(substr, i) where i is the fromindex which will return the index of first occurence of your substring. If you want the next occurence of substring you **will set the fromindex with a value which will be sum of length of substring and index of previous substring** found in previous iteration.
I think your function will not work properly.It should be something like

```
   public static int keywordCount( String str, String substr){
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((i=str.indexOf(substr, i)) != -1) {
            count++;
            i += substr.length();
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }
```